# Retrospection on Float, Real and Decimal data types

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to understand the repercussions of having a column with **real** data type in a database(**Sql Server**) table, in my scenario. I have a column in my database with **real** datatype. **The data is static**, its always one of the values in range 0.0, 0.1, 0.2.. to 1.0.

**Use Case:**
I have to Sum up the values in the column and use the sum value in some arithmetic calculations which include financial data.

**Concern?:**
When I sum up values in the column it gives me result with more decimal places.

**Test:**

1. I want sum up the column values and use it in multiplication and division calculations.
2. I want to repeat #1 for same set of values in a column with decimal and float data types.

**Procedure:** I have created three different tables with a single column and same set of values but different data types, one with decimal, float and real. And perform the arithmetic calculations on each of them.

```
     CREATE TABLE #tReal(d real);
     INSERT INTO #tReal
     SELECT 0.1 UNION ALL 
     SELECT 1 UNION ALL 
     SELECT 1 UNION ALL 
     SELECT 0.9 UNION ALL 
     SELECT 1 UNION ALL 
     SELECT 0.9 UNION ALL 
     SELECT 1;
     select SUM(d) from #tReal
```

**Expected Result : 5.9**

**Actual Result :** **5.8999999538064**

And, If I perform round operation on the sum the result is as expected

```
declare @sumofd real
select @sumofd = SUM(d) from #tReal
select round(@sumofd , 1)
```

**Result: 5.9**

Also, if I update datatype from ***real*** to ***float***

```
CREATE TABLE #tfloat(d float);
INSERT INTO #tfloat
SELECT 0.1 UNION ALL 
SELECT 1 UNION ALL 
SELECT 1 UNION ALL 
SELECT 0.9 UNION ALL 
SELECT 1 UNION ALL 
SELECT 0.9 UNION ALL 
SELECT 1;
select SUM(d) from #tfloat
```

**Expected Result : 5.9**

**Actual Result :** **5.9**

And, This is the same case if I update datatype from ***real*** to ***decimal***

```
CREATE TABLE #tDecimal(d DECIMAL(3,2));
INSERT INTO #tDecimal
SELECT 0.1 UNION ALL 
SELECT 1 UNION ALL 
SELECT 1 UNION ALL 
SELECT 0.9 UNION ALL 
SELECT 1 UNION ALL 
SELECT 0.9 UNION ALL 
SELECT 1;

select SUM(d) from #tDecimal
```

**Expected Result : 5.94**

**Actual Result :** **5.94**

And, If I perform some basic arithmetic operations on the sum, without rounding, like

```
declare @sumofdReal real
declare @sumofdFloat float
declare @sumofdDecimal decimal(3,2)

select @sumofdReal = SUM(d) from #tReal
select @sumofdFloat = SUM(d) from #tfloat
select @sumofdDecimal = SUM(d) from #tDecimal
```

Multiplication:

```
select @sumofdReal * 2
Result: 11.8

select @sumofdFloat * 2
Result: 11.8

select @sumofdDecimal * 2
Result: 11.88
```

Division:

```
select @sumofdReal / 2
Result: 2.95

select @sumofdFloat / 2
Result: 2.95

select @sumofdDecimal / 2
Result: 2.97000
```

Drop Tables:

```
drop table #tReal
drop table #tfloat
drop table #tDecimal
```

Following are my questions

1. In my scenario, having a datatype as real will have any repercussions?
2. If #1 is yes, what kind of repercussions? Do I have to change datatype to float or decimal? Why?
3. If #1 is No, Why? Please explain?

**Is there a point to which float and real types can produce exact result and anything beyond it rounding errors will show up?**

Comment: Is there an error in your example for the decimal section - why is your expected result 5.9?  Your last value is 0.944.

Comment: Why do you expect to get 5.9 from the decimal calculation, a decimal(3,2) has a precision of 2 decimal places.

Comment: @Paddy It was a typo. Updated with proper value.

Comment: Your example for decimal is simply wrong:  http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/579e3.

Comment: @Mady, since your edit your sums don't add up any more.

Comment: @GordonLinoff  how it is wrong? Output in fiddle is 5.9, but in sqlserver it is 5.94.

Answer (score 1):

[`real`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173773.aspx) in SQL Server is a synonym for `float(24)`, which takes 4 bytes and up to 7 digits of precision.

`float` by itself is the same as `float(53)` which is also the same as `double` which takes up 8 bytes and has up to 15 digits of precision.

> In my scenario, having a datatype as real will have any repercussions?

Possibly.  `decimal`, `float`, and `real` [have different characteristics and are not fully interchangeable](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms187912.aspx).  If you want to maintain the exact decimal representation, use the `decimal` datatype with the appropriate scale and precision.  If your numbers represent imprecise data (such as temperature, height, time, or other "natural" measurements that cannot be measured without some imprecision) and want faster mathematical operations then use `float` (or `real` if you don;t need more than 7 digits of precision.

> When I sum up values in the column it gives me result with more decimal places.

When you add floating point numbers, SQL determines how big the result can be and will use the appropriate data type.  When you add two `reals`, the result *could* have more than 7 digits of precision, so it may use `float` as the resulting data type.

> Do I have to change datatype to float or decimal? Why?

Use `float` if you may have more than 7 digits of precision, don't need absolute precision from a decimal standpoint, and want to use a floating-point type for faster calculations.

If you want a fixed scale and precision and want to minimize the imprecision involved with floating point numbers use `decimal`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using these values in financial calculations, then you should always (pretty much) use decimal types, otherwise you will run into issues with floating point rounding at some point.  People get very wound up when you start losing pennies.

You may want to read some more on floating point arithmetic here:

http://floating-point-gui.de/

Decimal types will not be subject to these and should be exact.

---

For an example, you will eventually run into the situation where you try and round a number to 2 DP, e.g. 0.695, which you would expect to round up to 0.70.

```
DECLARE @x REAL = 0.695

SELECT ROUND(@x, 2)

-- outputs 0.69

DECLARE @y DECIMAL(6,4) = 0.695

SELECT ROUND(@y, 2)

-- outputs 0.7000
```

This is down to the fact that you cannot accurately represent 0.695 as a floating point number and it is in fact marginally less than 0.695 as saved.

Comment: That is precisely I want to understand it with an example since I read this theory earlier. If you look at the Multiplication calculation result is similar for all three. There is some variation in division calculation not sure why?

Comment: Is there a point to which float and real types can produce exact result and anything beyond it rounding errors will show up?

Comment: No, it is always there as a potential issue.  In your example you include the number 0.1 - this is not exactly represented as a float (see here: http://www.exploringbinary.com/why-0-point-1-does-not-exist-in-floating-point/).  At some point, depending on your calculation, you will find that these small deltas can make a difference in your expected output.

Answer (score 0):

Working with floating-point values always has repercussions, because they are not represented exactly and some rounding errors will always occur. You have to be most careful when comparing values with constants, e.g. if (a == 0.0) as this won't always work if 'a' is the result of mathematical operations. Float and Decimal just give you different ranges and precisions.